# What causes duplicates in my Employee Directory (People Search Results) page in SP2013?

Tags: 2013, directory

I apologize in advance for being a newbie, but I'm charged with creating an Employee Directory.  I'm using the instructions in [this article](http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/), but I'm a little perplexed by the results.

I have "Administrator" and "SP_*" and other accounts that I don't want to show up in the directory right now.  I also have some employees that are no longer her, and I have one account that shows up twice, once as "First Last" and also "First M Last."

A) Is there a way I can filter what shows up?
B) Can I just delete the offending accounts?

Where do I add new users?  What's the source of these employees?  I mean, I know it's "SPSPeople" but what does that MEAN?  How do I add/remove people from SPSPeople?

Thanks for helping this newbie out.